# Where to ask this question: 'For any given English writing, what is the probability that an author studied some Latin?'

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I tried already on [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/23374/8309) and then [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257680/for-any-given-english-writing-what-is-the-probability-that-an-author-studied-so#comment564776_257680), but both sites deemed my question 'off-topic'.

Also, please feel free to suggest improvements to make on-topic my question, as follows:

> Premise 1: This question is restricted to (at least average) writing in only English, by which I mean writing by someone who at least graduated from high school. I lament, but know, that the uneducated would not have learned Latin.
>
> By the 1960s, Latin education had already been reduced and superseded
>   ([per this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/12099/8309)).
>   So authors born after 1959 probably did not study Latin as a mandatory
>   subject, unless they attended a [Latin
>   school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_school) (eg Boston Latin
>   Academy in the US).
>
> So suppose that you are given any writing satisfying premise 1 above,
>   and you know its year of publication. For all (documented) years,
>   what's the rough probability of some study of Latin by the author (but
>   whose proficiency may still < 100%)? I assume:
>
> 2.  the lack of an explicit answer from research or biographies,
>
> 3. the unknownness of the author's identity (eg an editorial or an
>   advertisement).

Comment: Maybe Linguistics or Writers? But the question could be a bit broad

Comment: @santiago Thanks. I added your concern of broadness to my OP.

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate on some sort of math/analytic site... You're asking for a probability, which means someone would have to figure out the likelihood of someone having learned Latin in any given year... But... There's not likely a way to know for sure if any given writer learned Latin.

Comment: It's probably impossible to answer except in extremely broad terms.  Also, since Latin has been a dead language for a very, very long time, the odds of having a proficiency < 100% are themselves 100%.

Comment: This sounds like a machine learning problem.